# MailKit Fetch Syntax error in untagged FETCH response. Unexpected token: '\\n'

Tags: c#, mailkit

I have seen a couple of questions regarding this, but none of them seems to match the one that I'm encountring, hence creating this questions.

I have one mailbox (it's the first and the only one I see this issue with), running against a Domino server. When it is trying to FETCH the inbox of this account, it reads

```
foreach (var summary in client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, Items).Where(x => 
    (x.Flags & MessageFlags.Deleted) != MessageFlags.Deleted &&
    (x.Flags & MessageFlags.Seen) != MessageFlags.Seen))
    {
        //Do something...
    }
```

Last entry in my imap protocollog is this:

```
S:  FLAGS (\Seen))      
S: * 8303 FETCH (UID 8303 ENVELOPE ({..MASKED..}) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (REFERENCES)] {4}      
S: 
S: 
S:  FLAGS (\Seen))
```

There is no FETCH COMPLETE in this log, and it seems like sometimes the log is bigger (more emails fetched) than others. The exception is always the same, unexpeced token \n.

UPDATE regarding atom token exception:

```
{"Syntax error in ENVELOPE. Unexpected token: [atom: <user@domain.orguser]"}


S:  FLAGS (\Seen))
S: * 19607 FETCH (UID 19607 ENVELOPE ("Wed, 8 Nov 2014 13:50:09 +0100" "Re: LDAP Filter" (("DisplayName1" NIL "dn1" "domain2.invalid")) (("DisplayName1" NIL "dn1" "domain2.invalid")) (("DisplayName1" NIL "dn1" "domain2.invalid")) (("DisplayName4" NIL "dn4" "domain1.invalid")("DisplayName3" NIL "dn3" "domain3.invalid")) (("DisplayName2" NIL "dn2" "domain2.invalid")("user@domain.org" NIL "user" "domain.org> "ss@domain.org" <user@domain.orguser")) NIL "<OF4C7FF16B.1B0A6826-ONC1257D6B.003FBF81-C1257D6B.00400501@LocalDomain>" "<OF31482F53.2CA9A4AC-ONC1257D6B.004080EE-C1257D6B.00410453@LocalDomain>") BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (REFERENCES SUBJECT)] {235}
S: Subject: Re: LDAP Filter
S: References: <3A5893A9FA8E964D862DAA1FA2B5E9EA1BCD89@OESTMB701.domain1.invalid>
S:  <3A5893A9FA8E964D862DAA1FA2B5E9EA1C1A45@OESTMB701.domain1.invalid>
S:  <OF4C7FF16B.1B0A6826-ONC1257D6B.003FBF81-C1257D6B.00400501@LocalDomain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that it encountered an unexpected newline character. The problem is *probably* that the header parser isn't consuming all 4 bytes of the empty header blob (it's probably just consuming the first blank line).

A work-around might be to request a header that does exist as well as the REFERENCES header (maybe SUBJECT).

```
var headers = new HashSet<string> ();
headers.Add ("REFERENCES");
headers.Add ("SUBJECT");

var items = folder.Fetch (0, -1, summaryItemFlags, headers);
```

Comment: My "Items" in the Fetch() is as follows: `code`private const MessageSummaryItems Items =
            MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Flags |
            MessageSummaryItems.References;`code` Can't really see a SUBJECT header option in that enumerate, probably since it's a part of the ENVELOPE?

Comment: As a follow-up on my previous comment, I can confirm that if I remove the REFERENCES item, the same exception is not encountered, so I think we can conclude the issue persist to incorrect reference header. Awaiting your response on the work-around. Also, I'm getting another exception, regarding Atom token in an Envelope: Syntax error in ENVELOPE Unexpected token: [atom: {"masked"}]

Comment: I’m going to need to see a protocol log to see where this masked token is

Comment: The "masked" token is an email address, hence the masking :) But could you give an example of how to do the work-around that you posted?

Comment: Updated my answer to show you. I've also committed a likely fix for this here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/commit/5a0f2bc05fd37f632e6667db364f7718653521d2

Comment: I tried adding the headers as shown in your example, but unfortunately, it did not prevent the \\n token exception. I would like to try the last commitments you did. Do you have any ideas of when next release is? Regarding the atom token thing, I realized it due to corrupted/missing tags in the field: "Syntax error in ENVELOPE. Unexpected token: [atom: <{"MASKED EMAIL"}]" . For me it seems like it has no ending (>) tag of <. Also, I updated the MailKit nuget to the latest released (1.20.0).

Comment: I was hoping not to make a release until it's been verified that my patch actually fixes the problem. Would you be willing to test it?

Comment: Also IMAP doesn't send email addresses surrounded with <>'s, so that's not likely to be the problem. It splits them into LISP tokens. For example, `Real Name <user@gmail.com>` would be sent by IMAP as `("Real Name" NIL "user" "gmail.com")`

Comment: Then I am not sure what happened on the case where the Atom is reporting a unexpected token exception.
I'll grab the changes from github, and report back if they fix the issue with \n tokens that I experience (on monday)

Comment: Tested with the master from Git, but I cannot confirm whether it has been fixed or not, as I keep getting the ´Syntax error in ENVELOPE. Unexpected token: [atom:´. I updated my question with latest findings regarding this issue, interesting is that the response from server actually contains '("user@domain.org" NIL "user" "domain.org> "ss@domain.org" <user@domain.orguser")' in the envelope, which I think will cause issues in MailKit?

Comment: Yes, because of the badly quoted tokens. My guess is that your IMAP server is not dealing well with whatever that raw email address is.

Comment: But are there any work-around for this? In this case it is an incoming email that "destroyed" the fetch of the inbox, it would be a bit bad if anyone could destroy the service by sending some invalid values as mail headers.

Comment: That’s why your IMAP server should be fixed :)

Comment: If you forget to add a ; at the end of a line when programming, does the compiler continue without error? No, of course not and that’s a far easier situation to recover from than this.

Comment: In this case it's a Lotus Notes server, I doubt that would ever be fixed :D

Comment: Submit a bug report to them anyway. You won’t know until you try.

Comment: I was wondering a thing, how come that the exactly same mailbox is working, using the notes client with an IMAP configuration? I mean, if this is a protocol violation to IMAP, then I guess it would persist anywhere.

Comment: If you can find in the IMAP spec where that is ok, I’ll eat my foot and fix MailKit. How’s that? :)

Comment: A bit late, but I can finally confirm that your fix in trunk seems to work. At least I don't get any exception wih '/n' tokens anymore, after I removed a couple of emails, that had 'atom' token violation, most of them due to invalid CC fields (that Notes server seems to carry on) like i.e. CC: mail1@invalid.org, mail2@invalid.org mail3@invalid.org (note the missing comma-seperation between mail2 and mail3).